# How to get records count greater than x (using MySQL Query) in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, group-by

```
$lists = DB::table('searches')->orderBy('query', 'DESC')->paginate(15);

@foreach ($lists as list)
  <div> {{$list->name}} </div>
@endforeach
```

I did write this query and It shows:

**Apple Apple Apple Apple Apple Apple Banana Banana Banana Grapes Grapes Orange  ....**

I want to show only the names of the fruits having an overall count of occurences greater than 3 (if **count>3**)
I used:

```
DB::select('SELECT query, count(*) as count FROM searches GROUP BY query HAVING count > 3');
```

but in view file I cannot count by `$lists->count()`

Error:
**Call to a member function count() on array**

I want my output as:
**Apple Banana ...**
`and $lists->count()` as **2**

Since **Orange** and **Grapes** count < 3 so they won't be included in the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get records by using **selectRaw** and **havingRaw**

```
DB::table('searches')->selectRaw('query,count(*) as count')->groupBy('query')->havingRaw('count(*) > 3')->orderBy('query', 'DESC')->paginate(15);
```

This query will give output 15 records (**as defined in paginate(15)**) when the value count is GREATER than 3.

Comment: it is good. But if I want to get the ID of query as well ? how can I?

Comment: If the ID value is different every time, then you can't achieve what you are looking for..but if ID value is the same every time you can add it within selectRaw() and groupBy()

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure to understand what exactly you want, but I guess you'd want to use a GROUP BY and HAVING

```
SELECT name, count(*)
FROM fruits
WHERE ...
GROUP BY name
HAVING count(*) > 3
```

This query will count the number of records of the same name, but only if the count is greater than 3-

Comment: I got you but how to include it with DB::table('searches')->orderBy('query', 'DESC')->paginate(15)  Since yours is MYSQL command

Comment: That's a different question... you're using a framework or something? Then consult the documentation about how to do that, I do not know any details. Sorry

Comment: @Riya simply follow `DB::statement("your query");` or `DB::select("your query");`

Answer (score -1):

using the ->simplePaginate()